# How can I determine which setting entry will color something in the code editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get my colors set up in Visual Studio 2015 the way I like them and there are still some things that are colored different from the way I like. Is there a general purpose way to find out what the Visual Studio editor is classifying a token as?

Alternatively, two things I'm trying to change the color of are the C# global namespace keyword (it doesn't count under Keyword) and the highlighting of some refactoring suggestions. If someone knows the name of the color setting controlling these, that would solve my immediate problems.

Edit: Here is a screenshot showing these two examples.
[image]
"global" is purple instead of blue, as my keywords are set. "Attribute" is grayed out instead of solid because of a refactor suggestion which appears if I mouse over it.

Comment: Check this [link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-your-ide-hot-or-not/)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the link you wanted to share. I already know how to customize colors, but I'm trying to locate which color names I need.

Comment: I understand your question, but it would be better you can provide some samples: a few lines of sample code or screenshot. It will attract more answers.

Comment: @RichardRobertson can you elaborate more or any example ?

Comment: Edited post with screenshot.

Comment: Strangely, `global` *does* count under Keyword in my settings in that context. There does not appear to be a way to change how refactoring suggestions are highlighted - they're always semitransparent. I'm using VS2015 Community RTM on Windows 10.

Comment: I only have VS2013 here right now, but there it’s “Keyword”; I’ll check in a bit with VS2015. Considering that refactor suggestion, are you sure you don’t have some extension installed, e.g. ReSharper, that adds lots of syntax color definitions?

Comment: @poke: This is definitely baked into VS2015 now. Apparently. Never had this in VS2013 either. As far as I can tell 2015 changed quite a number of syntax coloring settings - my 2013 settings did not correctly migrate over.

Comment: Yes. It was "Keyword" in 2013, and I've already got it set to blue in my 2015 settings. As far as extensions, I just installed a vanilla 2015 community edition.

Comment: Ok, thanks for those who tried to help. It appears that I am just dealing with a lack of customization on refactor suggestions.